# Send an email from repository is not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to send an email from a repository class in my compose app like this.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

// add three fields to intent using putExtra function
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(emailTo));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailbody);

// set type of intent
intent.setType("message/rfc822");

// startActivity with intent with chooser as Email client using createChooser function
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"))
```

Context is injected in repository constructor like this using `Hilt`

```
@ApplicationContext private val context: Context
```

Despite I'm already adding the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` this code is trowing the following error

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: "I'm trying to send an email from a repository class in my compose app like this" -- IMHO, that's architectually unwise. "Is there anything wrong with my approach?" -- the `Intent` created by `Intent.createChooser()` does not have the flag.

Comment: @CommonsWare: how would you do it? Would you send a message to the UI layer to send the email?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi "Would you send a message to the UI layer to send the email?" -- yes. Partly, that gives you an `Activity` to use. Partly, outside of very extreme cases, IMHO it is the UI layer's job to navigate to third-party apps. Alternatively, if you don't want the third-party app sending the email, have your Web service do it.